# Setting priority with ActiveJob when using Delayed::Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, rails-activejob

How do you set the delayed job priority when using ActiveJob to enqueue your jobs?

```
class GuestsCleanupJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :high_priority

  def perform(*guests)
    # Do something later
  end
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It took me a while, but I found this method in the Delayed::Job documentation:

```
Delayed::Worker.queue_attributes = {
  default:       { priority: 11 },
  high_priority: { priority: 1 },
  low_priority:  { priority: 75 }
}
```

I've added this to my initializers and just wanted to share if anyone else runs into this!

Answer (score 4):

defining an instance method that defines priority works, however is doesn't allow me to overload the value.
Given this class

```
class GuestsCleanupJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :high_priority

  def priority
    1
  end

  def perform(*guests)
    # Do something later
  end
end
```

if I run

```
GuestsCleanupJob.set(priority: 55).perform_later(user, lead) # priority set to 1 not 55
```

It will queue up a job with priority 1, and ignore the 55 I passed.

That didn't provide enough control for my use-case so instead I did.

```
class GuestsCleanupJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :high_priority

  def default_priority
    1
  end

  def priority
    @priority || default_priority
  end

  def perform(*guests)
    # Do something later
  end
end
```

Using the above code, by default the priority will be set to one, but I can use my

```
GuestsCleanupJob.set(priority: 55).perform_later(user, lead) # priority set to 55
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use the `set` indicated by the documentation to specify a queue. `
MyJob.set(queue: :another_queue).perform_later(record)`  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

Answer (score 3):

The solution using Delayed::Worker.queue_attributes, looks ok and it is documented, but it didn't work for me ...
All the jobs had priority=0 regardless the queue priority set in queue_attributes.
This worked for me:

```
class GuestsCleanupJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :high_priority

  def priority
    1
  end

  def perform(*guests)
    # Do something later
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To follow the pattern of `queue_as` you could also use `queue_with_priority` like:

```rb
class GuestsCleanupJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :high_priority
  queue_with_priority 1

  def perform(*guests)
    # Do something later
  end
end
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueuePriority/ClassMethods.html#method-i-queue_with_priority